# How do I import a package in vyper version 0.4.0^?

Tags: python, vyper

For example, let's say I want to import [snekmate](https://github.com/pcaversaccio/snekmate/blob/main/src/snekmate/tokens/ERC20.vy):

```py
from snekmate.tokens import ERC20 as base_token
```

How do I get `snekmate` into my packages? Do I have to import them to my `contracts` folder?